# Find upper triangular matrix C such that Cx=y

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]

In the image above, how does one know that $c=e$ and $c$ is not equal to $f$? and $e$ is not equal to $f$? How does one know that $b=d$?

Comment: @Moo how do you know what can be a "Free Variable" and what cannot be a "Free Variable"? How do you know what are/is the free variable and bounded variables?

Comment: Solve from the bottom up. $f = -1/9, d = 3e, a = 1/5(2 - 3 b + 9 c)$. This means you can choose whatever you like for $e, b, c$, so $e, b, c$ are free variables.

Comment: When you have more variables than equations, the only way to make sense of a solution is to decide the values of some of the variables. In this case, we have 2 equations and 5 variables. We must assign a value to 3 of the variables so that each of the 2 equations has only one variable left.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment:** The idea is that there are not enough "conditions" ("restrictions", "relationships") imposed to determine each variable uniquely. So you are free to assign values to unrestricted variables.

For a more simple concrete example, suppose you are asked to find all solutions $(x,y)$ to the equation $x+ y=1$, where $x$ and $y$ are real numbers. You might immediately think of taking $x=1$ and $y=0$ (the solution $(1,0)$). Then you would probably realize you could have done it the other way around, $x=0$ and $y=1$ (the solution $(0,1)$). Then there is $x=42$ and $y=-41$ (the solution $(42,-41)$) et cetera. More generally, you could pick any value for $x$, and put $y=1-x$, and that would be a solution $(x,1-x)$. In fact, **all** solutions are of this form.

You could further simplify this general solution here by writing it as $(0,1)+x(1,-1)$. Here the value of $x$ may be chosen freely.